# Polymorphism using C# and MongoDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mongodb, polymorphism

I'm trying to use MongoDB for the first time using C#, but I'm struggling to implement polymorphism. A short summary of what I'm trying to achieve:

- A project contains multiple Items
- An Item can either be a Directory or a Bookmark
- A Directory is a collection of other Directories or Bookmarks (Items)

I'm struggling with the second part. I used [this](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/#polymorphism) as a reference, but whenever I try to get a project from the database, it contains a list of Items instead of either Bookmarks or Directories, and thus ignoring the Url of a Bookmark. I also found this [Github repo](https://gist.github.com/sindbach/4234caa968f059c6a897c4088d6b98b0) which seems to accomplish the same thing, but I cannot implement it because I already have a .Find(). in my GetProjectByIdAsync method.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Project.cs:

```
public class Project
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Item.cs:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements(true)]
[BsonDiscriminator(RootClass = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Directory), typeof(Bookmark))]
public abstract class Item
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }}
}
```

Directory.cs:

```
public class Directory: Item 
{
     public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Bookmark.cs:

```
public class Bookmark: Item
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

ProjectService.cs:

```
public async Task<Project> GetProjectByIdAsync(string id)
{
    return await _projects.Find(project => project.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

The data does seem to be stored in the database in the correct way:
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it contains a list of items"? Bear in mind that `Item` is am abstract class so you can't create an instance of it.

Comment: @Llama Each project contains a list that consists of Bookmarks and Directories

Comment: A List<Item> contains Item instances. If you get returned something derived from Item in that list you will still only see the Item things in code as the variable pointing to it will be of type item. If you want to see more you need to cast it to the concrete class.

Comment: OK. And what is your expectation? It's always going to be a List<Item>

Comment: I think I made a design error, I tought it was possible this way, but appearently it is not. I have changed my Project class to hold a seperate list of Directories and Bookmarks, this seems to be working.